# Potential leak of memory pointed to by 'distance' ? (how a dynamic array works with class)

Tags: c++, class, dynamic-arrays

I need to fill a dynamic array with a variable from a class.  My assignment is to fill an array "distance" with a `Point` (x and y), and in each cell of the array I calculate the distance (with a function) between two points as well as the perimeter with all the distances.

I don't know if it's very clear but I'm a beginner in c++.  Please help me!!  Thank you

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Point.h"
#include "Polygone.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int numberSide;
    int x1, y1, x2, y2;
    Point p1, p2;
    cout<<"enter number of sides:"<<endl;
    cin>>numberSide;
    float* distance=new float(numberSide);
    cout<<"enter points:"<<endl;
    for (int i=0; i<numberSide; i++) {
        cin>>x1>>y1;
        Point p1(x1,y1);
        cin>>x2>>y2;
        Point p2(x2,y2);
        distance[i]=p1.distance(p1, p2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `p1` and `p2` are automatic variables and are re-declared in the `for` block, so their lifetime is the block: no leak problem here. SImply there is no reason to declare it outside of that block. For `distance`, it is allocated with `new[]` so it should be de-allocated with `delete[]` when it is no longer required.

Comment: Thank u it worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allocate like this:

```
 float *distance = new float[numberSide];
```

Free memory like this:

```
delete [] distance;
```

Comment: @Elish good! please check on "ok" if this post answer your question ^^

Comment: where i check on ok?

Comment: @Elish on the left of my answer, there is a UPvote button, DownVote button and OK button to indicate that the answer answers the question